# Use ::before on a <select name="aaa"> element

Tags: label, element

I'm editing a css style sheet to use as an override on a template that I have no access to. I am wondering if it is possible to use a `::before` on a `<select name="aaa">` element that has no class or id to isolate it. Basically trying to put a label/icon before the select menu to make things a bit clearer.

```
<div class="container">
    <select name="selection1">...</select>
    <select name="selection2">...</select>
</div>
```

I've tried too many variations to mention and been hunting about with no luck. So I presume it's not possible. But you never know.

Comment: U can do it easily with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

<select> doesn't allow for pseudo ::before or ::after.  You can use a javascript solution or wrap each individual  in a div.  Not the greatest solution, but hope it helps.